# Visual Studio check in copy of linked file (TFVC)

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, tfvc

I was using the same File in 3 Different Project so I added the File as a link to my other 2 Projects, so when I change the file in one Project it gets changed in all of them. But now my Problem is when I check my Project in (TFVC) my CI pipline trys building the project but its missing the linked File: (I actually have 8 linked files)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an solution to the problem in azure Devops you can add a second project to the checkout, just use the + Button

Sorry for German:
[image]